# How good are Taiwanese universities for getting PhD in Industrial Engineering?

Tags: phd, career-path, engineering

My cousins have recommended me to pursue my Ph.D. in Taiwan instead of wasting my time, email constantly to professors to many professors in Europe, The United States, Canada, Australia,..., with a little tangible outcome (not responding to my email, or have financial restriction, or unable to accept further Ph.D. student), and after graduation, I can immigrate to another country such as Australia for work. I do not know a lot about Taiwan, and I do not know if it is worth to spend my time going to Taiwan. Is worth it? I do not know if a country like Australia or Canada accepts my Ph.D. degree. I live in Iran actually and due to economical conditions, political conditions, and social conditions, many well-educated people tend to move out of the country in hope of a better job or life condition. Although the COVIDE-19 pandemic make everything or future unclear

Comment: I am going to pursue operation research which can be found in those three fields.

Comment: Please send e-mail to [College of Management](https://www.ntu.edu.tw/english/academics/academics_management.html) to ask about  the admission procedures. I am not in your field, I can't tell you how good they are.

Comment: Also, I just found [this](http://www.ie.nthu.edu.tw/p/412-1310-6270.php?Lang=en). Contact them, then make your own judgment.

Comment: Thnak you for your comments and advice

Comment: It is interesting you have no luck in Australia.  I have many students from Iran applying for next year.

Comment: For Australia, specifically, I have to write a proposal. I do not have problem with this. Without a doubt, the proposal is not seamless and I have to check with a prospective supervisor. I have 3 topics that I am currently working on it. I send many emails to supervisors that I think have a same research interest and employ almost the same methodology. Besides, I have to make sure about the uniqueness of my thesis projects. But I do not recieve a single response. Some universities ask us to secure a potential superviosr before sending our application, without which the do not consider our app.